# Unable to rewrite "http://www" to "http://" in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website and am trying to rewrite all urls with 'http://www...' to 'http://...'

This is the content of my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options -Multiviews
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]

    #RewriteBase /employers/
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ employers/page.php?page=$1 [L]

    #RewriteBase /candidates/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([^/]+)/?$ candidates/read.php?page=$1&year=$2&month=$3&slug=$4 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This correctly rewrites these types of urls: www.example.com, www.example.com/index.php

The problem is that it does not rewrite  these types: www.example.com/candidates/, www.example.com/candidates/login.php

How can i fix this thanks!

**EDIT**

I have a .htaccess in my candidates folder and this is the content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d{4})/(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])/([^/]+)/?$ read.php?page=$1&year=$2&month=$3&slug=$4 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now if i comment on it, the rewrite rule rewrites properly to 'http://'.

My question:
1. How does the .htaccess affect the 'http://' rewriting?
2. How can i fix it

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually tested your code above, and it actually works for me!

What I realized though, is that my browser tended to cache the .htaccess settings, and not update even if I changed things, so I'd recommend making a total cleanup of the browser cache and see what happens then. I'm quite sure this helps.

What you could also double-check, is that there are no local .htaccess files under the folders "candidtates" and "employers".

Comment: You are right, there is a htaccess file in the candidates folder, kindly check my edit for details. thanks

Comment: Since it seems that the .htaccess in the candidates folder is a duplicate of the last chunk of rules in the main one, so I don't see why you would need to have this local .htaccess file (which probably somehow gets precedence over the main one, when surfing in the local folder ... though I could be wrong ...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add a `L` (Last) to your first rewrite rule. Like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

(which will mean that upon rewriting the domain Apache will stop processing the rest of the rules and will just return a 301 response)

Comment: i did this it, did not change it

Answer (score 0):

What if you place the two lines:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$`
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

... at the end? This kind of change often solved things for me. (I guess the "RewriteCond" can screw things up, if it applies to things below it, which it is not supposed to ...)

Comment: i swapped the positions didnt help, any other clue?